# Upload a folder structure into box.com using v2 API

Tags: box-api, box

Do we have any V2 APIs for box.com which will allow me to upload a folder structure?

I have a folder with the below structure:

main_folder

- sub1_folder (Has sub1_file1 and sub1_file2)
- sub2_folder (Has sub2_file1 and sub2_file2)

I want to upload 'main_folder'. main_folder has been created on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way of uploading an entire folder. You will need to recursively walk through "main_folder" and manually create child folders and upload files as you go.